# Mixing expression, plain text and newline in ggplot2 expression

Tags: r, ggplot2, mathematical-expressions

I am trying to create some labels/stickers using `ggplot2`.
I am pulling the text for the labels from a source and tyring to plot. I am able to do that as follows:

```
labtxt1 <- c("This text should be bold", "This text should also be bold", "Another text to be bold")
labtxt1 <- strwrap(labtxt1, width = 20)

labtxt2 <- c("This text should not be bold", "This text should also not be bold", "Another text to be plain")
labtxt2 <- strwrap(labtxt2, width = 20)

library(ggplot2)
library(Hmisc)

labtxt <- c(labtxt1, labtxt2)
labtxt <- paste(labtxt, collapse = "\n", sep = "")
labtxt <- escapeRegex(labtxt)

ggplot(x=1, y = 1) + 
  annotate("text", x = 0.5, y = 0.5, 
           label = labtxt,
           colour = "red", parse = F, lineheight = 0.8)
```

[image]

How to now make the text in `labtxt1` to bold, along with the text in `labtxt2` as plain maintaining the justification and `linewidth`?

I have tried with `expression` with `\n`, which messes up the justification, and  with `atop`, but which messes up the linewidth.

If I try to annotate separately, then positioning is difficult as the lenght of `labtxt1` and `labtxt2` varies in for different labels/stickers.

How to get the desired result?

Comment: Did you watch this [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568453/using-different-font-styles-in-annotate-ggplot2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31568453/using-different-font-styles-in-annotate-ggplot2)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could wrap the text in an invisible table,

```
library(ggplot2)
library(gridExtra)

label <- "plain text\nbold('bold line')\nitalic('italic line')\nplain again"
disect <- strsplit(label, "\\n")[[1]]

mytheme <- ttheme_minimal(core = list(fg_params = list(parse=TRUE, col="red",
                                                       hjust=0, x=0.1)))
tg <- tableGrob(as.matrix(disect), theme=mytheme)

ggplot(x=1, y = 1) + 
  annotation_custom(tg)
```